# How to merge these tables?

Tags: sas

I have the following code with me. It outputs 3 tables in the "results" section. Third table in the "results" section has the names of the variables along
with other details such as type, length, etc. I need to combine this third table for each of these data sets so that finally, I just have one table which has the names (and type, length, etc.) of all the variables that are there there in all of these tables.
Basically, my goal is to merge all the third tables in the "Results" section so as to get all this information in just one table.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
libname a meta library="abc" metaout=data;

data list;
     infile datalines4 dlm='|';
    format table $32.;
    input table;
datalines4;
table_a
table_b
table_c
table_d
table_e
table_f
table_g
table_h
;;;;
run;

data _null_;
    set list;
    call execute('
        proc contents data=a.'||strip(table)||';
        run;
    ');
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this information is already available in dictionary.columns and sashelp.cvcolumn metadata tables. No need to jump hoops like this.

```
data want;
   set sashelp.vcolumn;
   where libname = 'SASHELP';
run;
```